# Primefaces dataTable issues

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, refresh, primefaces

What is the method to refresh data on subsequent pages - second page, third page, etc - of a **Primefaces dataTable** using the **LazyDataModel** method?

Also, if I select an item in a dataTable to view its detail on another page, then came back to the dataTable using either the browser's Back button or implement JavaScript's history.back() method, it seems that the dataTable always reset its position to the first page instead of going back to the page the user was on. How can I force the dataTable to stay on the last viewed page?

My codes for lazy loading are:

```
private final class LazyLoader extends LazyDataModel<BookModel>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LazyLoader(String sort, String category, String operator, String input) {
        setListing(getBookService().getListing(sort, category, operator, input));
    }

    @Override
    public List<BookModel> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, boolean sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
        return getListing();
    }
}
```

And for the `Submit` method is:

```
public String Submit()
{
    sort     = sortBean.getSort();
    category = categoryBean.getCategory();
    operator = operatorBean.getOperator(); 
    input    = searchBean.getInput();

    lazyModel = new LazyLoader(sort, category, operator, input);
    lazyModel.setRowCount(listing.size());

    return null;
}
```

I'm using `@ViewScoped` for listing the book records as well as showing detail of a book record.

Does anyone has similar issues with Primefaces dataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep using `@ViewScoped`. You should not use `@SessionScoped` unless you have real needs for it.

To remember the last page, you have to set the `first` attribute of the `load` method. You can do that with request parameters. Something like: `yourview.xhtml?f=3` .

About the refreshing, the thing is that you are using a lazy loader but you're loading everything at once... Your `load` method is the one that should do the query *on demand*, that is, page by page.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, `@ViewScoped` is more than enough in my case. Okay, I'll try the request parameter method and review my `LazyLoader` method.

Comment: After much trials and errors, I've decided to implement my own data table and navigation using the standard Mojarra dataTable component. Primefaces dataTable does not seem to work. And seeing that I also provided Latin as well as non-Latin UTF-8 support (data entry, search, sort and filtering) in my web project, it's best to write my own methods to control the dataTable component. Might look at Primefaces dataTable again when version 4.x.x is out - could be different by then!... :)

Comment: Using `@ViewScoped` solved it for me. However, I have since moved to `OmniFaces` as the support and the Java library is much better than `PrimeFaces`.

Answer (score 0):

Does pagination work for you without lazy loading?  I would verify that works as expected before you jump into the hardest case.

If you want your dataTable to remember the last pagination after you navigate away from the JSF page then you need to make your managed bean SessionScoped.  The lifecycle of the ViewScoped managed bean ends after navigation leaves the view.

Comment: Further, I will add that to refresh the data on a lazy loaded dataTable then try instantiating and assigning a new LazyLoadDataModel.

Comment: @maple_shaft: I tried `@SessionScoped` and it makes no difference - the dataTable jumps to the first page as soon as I hit the browser's Back button or execute JavaScript's history.back() method. I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Yes, it works without lazy loading but I still have the issue of the dataTable jumping back to the first page.

Comment: I am saying, try to create a new LazyDataModel object and replace the one that you are referencing in your managed bean.  If this does not refresh the data in your table then their might be a problem with your getBookServer getListing code.

Comment: @maple_shaft: You mean doing it at the `LazyLoader` method? How?

Comment: @maple_shaft: It's not a question of English - it's because I don't know how to it - hence I'm asking the question here at Stackoverflow. I wouldn't ask it if I know how, would I? :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the selected page you have to do 2 things.

First make the managedBean session scoped.

Second set a binding between the datatable and a UIData object. In your backend bean for example put

```
private UIData filasUIData = null;

public UIData getFilasUIData() {
    return filasUIData;
}

public void setFilasUIData(UIData filasUIData) {
    this.filasUIData = filasUIData;
}
```

Now in your data table

```
<ice:dataTable
    binding="#{yourBean.filasUIData}"
```

that´s all.